# SSIS 2008: Can a package configuration contain a property not used by the package?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssis

I'm working with a client to update the client's ETL process. The current process uses SSIS 2008 R2. There is a custom execution mechanism which executes each package, and automatically applies a package configuration file.

There are about 100 SSIS packages needed to run the ETL. They are set up so that they all use the same names for connection managers, so that one configuration file can be applied to many packages.

The problem I am having, is that I need to add a new connection manager to just  one package. The way it looks like things work right now, I either need to make a special configuration just for this package, or I need to add the same connection manager to all the other packages, even though it is not used.

**Question:** Is it possible to have settings in a package configuration file that will be ignored the package has no property or object by that name? It seems like this throws an error, but I am not certain.

**Final Note:** I recognize that there are much better ways to do what my client is doing. However, they are on a strict timeline, and we strongly desire to modify the existing system as little as possible. Upgrading is not an option, nor is re-architecting the ETL process.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In SQL 2008 R2, you can have configs in a configuration file that are not used by the package.  Additionally, the package will still run even if it's configurations do not exist.

Comment: Addition from my research - it looks like it does throw errors when you invoke the package, but they don't seem to stop it from running.

Comment: Yes, it will throw a warning saying it could not apply the configuration.  This is not an Error, however, and so the package will continue to run.  Ideally, you would separate out connection manager configurations to their own files and apply multiple configurations to each package.  In this way, you would never need to reference a config that is not applicable to the package and throw unnecessary warnings.

Comment: There is one that says "error", when loading the config and unable to find a property, but it seems to be non-fatal. As far as multiple configurations, I agree. If I was doing this from a clean slate, it would be completely different. I'm trying to change the existing process as little as possible.